# Disallow multiple uses of password reset token

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

How can I make it so that using a Devise password reset token (i.e. just visiting the page, not necessarily actually resetting your password) makes that password reset token invalid for future use?

Comment: For context, I'm going off of this: https://robots.thoughtbot.com/is-your-site-leaking-password-reset-links

Comment: This article suggests a solution as well, and with code example. Is there a reason why you would not want to implement that?

Comment: The solution the article suggests (specifically, solution #1) is exactly what I want to implement. I don't see a code example in the article.

Comment: Are u not seeing links in “plugging the leak” section?

Comment: Those links link to examples for Clearance, not Devise, which works differently.